# Loading an image in Python (Error)

Tags: python, image

I want to load an image but I get an error-message.

My code:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("D:\Python26\PYTHON-PROGRAMME\bild.jpg")
im.show()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python26\PYTHON-PROGRAMME\00000000000000000", line 2, in <module>
    im = Image.open("D:\Python26\PYTHON-PROGRAMME\bild.jpg")
  File "D:\Python26\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1888, in open
    fp = __builtin__.open(fp, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'D:\\Python26\\PYTHON-PROGRAMME\x08ild.jpg'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to escape the backslashes:

```
im = Image.open("D:\\Python26\\PYTHON-PROGRAMME\\bild.jpg")
```

Comment: Or alternatively, use a raw string like so
 
    r"D:\Python26\PYTHON-PROGRAMME\bild.jpg"

Comment: @Noufal Ibrahim: True. I tend to use escapes, but that's personal taste, I guess.

Comment: The Windows runtime will accept forward slashes, too: "D:/Python26/PYTHON-PROGRAMME/bild.jpg"