# Image.open() not working for all images

Tags: python, file-io, python-imaging-library

```
from PIL import Image
imageFile ="C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\cbir-p\asf.jpg"
xsize, ysize=Image.open(imageFile).size
```

this code works perfectly for some images. If I use the same code for a different image it reports an error.

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\cbir-p\im1.py", line 5, in <module>
    xsize , ysize = Image.open(imageFile).size
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1993, in open
    fp = builtins.open(fp, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'C:\\Users\\Abhi\\Desktop\\cbir-p\x07sd.jpg'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading an image in Python (Error)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981138/loading-an-image-in-python-error)

Comment: I'm surprised it worked for 'some images'.

Answer (score 3):

Use a raw string for the file name.

```
imageFile = r'C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\cbir-p\asf.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os, sys
from PIL import Image

files = os.listdir('D:\Python')
for file in files:
    img = Image.open('D:\\Python\\0.jpg')
```